# what happens when user generates multiple keys for same service account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have an IAM service account in GCP wherein there's already 3 keys generated for that account, not sure who did it.
A user has requested for service account key in JSON format, which I don't have.
So I have some questions here:

1. User requested the service account **replacement key** in JSON. If I don't have original key, I can't replace that. Is it right?
2. Do I have to create a new key and delete others?
3. The keys generated won't impact the other users' work within the service account or do I need to share the JSON file with everyone who is accessing the service account.
4. The idea of generating a key is that different users will have different set of credentials to access the same account. Right?

Please review and suggest what should I do for this user's request to generate them a new key?

I thought of sharing the key_id with the user but since they need it in JSON format, I will have to create a new key for them. I am not sure though.

Comment: In my case, if a user create a service account key file, I shoot them! The user need a service account key file in only rare use case. It's unsafe to work with the simple file, with high level of criticality (you can be authenticated as the service account with that simple file). Prefer Service account impersonation instead!

Comment: I would suggest to approve the way your company works with the keys with some authority from a top security managers/architects/officers. Ideally (from my point of view) there should be an enforced organizational policy (if possible) which prevents creation and usage of generated keys at all.

Comment: If you lose the JSON key material, it cannot be downloaded again. You can delete a key and create a new one. However, you have a security mess. Get everyone together that requires keys and put key management under some form of management control. Losing track of a key is like losing a company credit card. That can be an expensive mistake.